# HTML5 canvas and BDD - Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, html5-canvas, bdd

I was learning about Behavior driven development (BDD) recently, i see that its good for CRUD web application.

Is BDD tools such as Cucumber suitable for games, specifically are they good for HTML5 Canvas games?

Is there any other BDD tools for HTML5 canvas games? Or Is BDD only for CRUD applications?

Comment: What is BDD? Do you have a link for it?

Comment: BDD is Behavior driven development. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: can you think of ways to interact with the canvas-based game in JavaScript?

Practically, could you open the JS console and interact with the game from there? Can you fire clicks at the right coordinates, can you press keys and most importantly, can you make assertions on what's being output by the game?

If the answer is yes, then you are able to automate the game in JavaScript and either Cucumber or Cucumber.js can definitely be used on top of that.

If the answer is no and you can't figure out a way to automate the canvas content in a similar fashion than what described above, then I'm afraid no automation tool could do the job.

To answer your second question: BDD has absolutely nothing to do with "CRUD" applications. It's about describing *behaviours* and automating examples that illustrate those behaviours. You can therefore take a BDD approach on virtually any types of application.

Shouldn't you find a way to automate your application, you could still consider writing scenarios to document the (expected) behaviour of your app. The automation phase is not mandatory, contrary to common beliefs :)

Answer (score 2):

I've just recently been experimenting with BDD and Games Development. But I'm building on the .NET & XNA Frameworks with C#. I'm using Visual Studio as my IDE and testing with SpecFlow and NUnit.

SpecFlow is the BDD/Gherkin tool - and as a group we've been talking about the game and fleshing out some requirements and documenting them in Gherkin... and going from there. The key is designing the game to be testable.

We've abstracted the game engine away from main "game loop" implementation that XNA requires so we are able to load it up and inject all of the dependencies it requires. We then run the tests on the engine and make asserts on the code afterwards to make sure that it is behaving correctly.

We decided early on that Graphics/Drawing/Sound/etc were out of scope of the testing... if they were broken in the end product, it would be very obvious. The test suite we've managed to build up just gives us the confidence that the mechanics of the game itself are working as intended (i.e. is game object A in the right location? does game object B die when hit with projectile C? etc. etc.).

So far it has been quite a good experience.

Comment: That's interesting and it's been a strategy we applied to heavy-JS web apps too. This is a compromise that can make acceptance testing viable on otherwise difficult-to-automate projects like games or asynchronous UI apps. Of course, this is a case-by-case decision.

Comment: Certainly case-by-case yes. I also think that certainly in the case of games it is very valuable to have a short prototype iteration first to quickly see if the game idea is worth heavily investing time in a a more time consuming process. In fact I'm not 100% sold on the concept of test driven games development... certainly for "one shot" releases with no planned upgrades/sequals/patches etc; especially for an indie games developer. But the concept works - and allows you to test the "engine" of the game without getting bogged with impossible asserts.